# How best to verify a client connection to elasticsearch using Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'd like a simple way of verifying that ES is available to a Java 
client. I have a factory that looks something like this to get a 
client instance:

https://gist.github.com/1364734

What's the best way to gracefully handle the scenario of ES not being 
available or is what I have sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shay previously confirmed that this approach is a good one.  The approach is backed up by [the documentation as well](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/transport/TransportClient.java#L279-L287).

As for gracefully handling.  You should just error the request or process that is attempting to execute the search.  It's possible the `TransportClient` becomes connected and future requests may succeed.

Copying your function here for the sake of completeness.

> ```
> private void verifyConnection(TransportClient client) {
>     ImmutableList<DiscoveryNode> nodes = client.connectedNodes();
>     if (nodes.isEmpty()) {
>         throw new ElasticSearchUnavailableException("No nodes available. Verify ES is running!");
>     } else {
>         log.info("connected to nodes: " + nodes.toString());
>     }
> }
> ```

From https://gist.github.com/1364734

Comment: downvoting as the answer didn't have any detail just a link and the link is dead

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra you should fix links or offer edits in the future.  Jumping on the down vote for a 6 year old question isn't very constructive.